# ens3: Host name lookup failure | sudo ifconfig up ens3

Tags: ifconfig, trisquel

On both the live image of Trisquel in a virtual machine:

```
$ sudo ifconfig up ens3
ens3: Host name lookup failure
ifconfig '--help' gives usage information
```

Answer (score 0):

The command is:

```
ifconfig ens3 up
```

You have the argument, which is the device name, and the subcommand in the wrong order.

I'm not familiar with Trisquel and don't have a VM to test but as it's GNU Linux, you should also be able to use the command:

```
ifup ens3
```